# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

I am a student and my job was to build my own IoC container. I've read some tutorials/code samples and finally created it but when I try to create instance of it, I get exception like in the topic. Here is my IoC code and test code, I've been trying to figure out what's wrong but just can't find it.

IoC

```
public class Mkontener: UnresolvedDependenciesException, IContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> container = new Dictionary<Type, object> { };

    public void Register(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
    {

        Type[] mytypes = assembly.GetTypes();


        foreach (Type t in mytypes)
        {
            if (!container.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                container.Add(t, Activator.CreateInstance(t));
            }
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Register(Type type)
    {
        if (!container.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            container.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Register(object impl)
    {
        Type t = impl.GetType();
        if (!container.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            container.Add(t, impl);
        }

        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Register<T>(Func<T> provider) where T : class
    {

        container.Add(provider.GetType(), provider);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {

        return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
    }

    public object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        List<ConstructorInfo> konstruktor = new List<ConstructorInfo> { };
        foreach (ConstructorInfo cons in type.GetConstructors())
        {
            konstruktor.Add(cons);
        }
        if (konstruktor.Count == 0)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        else
        {
            ConstructorInfo active = null;
            int lparams = 0;
            foreach (ConstructorInfo cnst in konstruktor)
            {
                int inner=0;
                foreach (ParameterInfo a in cnst.GetParameters())
                {
                    inner++;
                }
                if (inner > lparams)
                {
                    active = cnst;
                }

            }
            List<object> lista = new List<object> { };
            foreach(ParameterInfo param in active.GetParameters())
            {
                if (container.ContainsKey(param.GetType()))
                {
                    lista.Add(container[param.GetType()]);
                }
                else
                {
                    //throw new UnresolvedDependenciesException();
                }
            }

            object[] obiekty= lista.ToArray();
            return  Activator.CreateInstance(type, obiekty);
        }
        if (container.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return container[type];
        }
        else
        {
            //throw new UnresolvedDependenciesException();
        }

    }


    public void Register<T>(T impl) where T : class
    {
        container.Add(impl.GetType(), impl);
    }
}
```

Part of test unit

```
public void P1__Container_Should_Register_Singleton_As_Object()
{
    // Arrange
    var container = (IContainer)Activator.CreateInstance(LabDescriptor.Container);
    var singleton = new FakeImpl();

    // Act
    container.Register(singleton);
    var result = container.Resolve<IFake>();

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result, Is.SameAs(singleton));
}
```

Sorry for clumsy code etc. Just starting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just starting out, trying to reverse engineer an IOC container is not something you should really be trying to tackle. I've re-implemented your provided code, filling in some of the blanks, but from what I can see you're missing the point of a container.

```
class Mkontener: UnresolvedDependenciesException, IContainer
```

If Mkontener is going to be your container class, why is it extending what looks to be a custom exception as a base class? Also, you are trying to implement an IContainer interface. If this is ComponentModel's IContainer then your class will not compile. If you've created your own IContainer interface then I would suggest using a more appropriate name to avoid confusion/naming conflicts.

IOC containers work by either:
A) registering a concrete type against an interface. (And letting the container figure out how to set up a new instance of the concrete type when asked for the interface, and manage scope. i.e. singleton vs. instance per request)
B) registering a concrete instance against an interface. (classic Singleton behaviour)

Your implementation is doing neither.  Register needs to accept a concrete type and an interface type. Resolve would be told what interface to use, then construct (or return) an instance of the registered concrete type. A simple example like what you're trying to write is little more than a dynamic instance factory. The true power of an IoC container is knowing how to automatically resolve dependencies for objects when they are requested.

For example, given I have the following interfaces with implementations to match:
IRepository, ILoggingService, IDataService, IMessagingService, IAppController

Once each interface is registered with a given concrete type where constructors look like:
Repository(IDataService dataService, ILoggingService loggingService)
MessagingService(ILoggingService loggingService)
AppController(IRepository repository, IMessagingService messagingService)

Registering each would look something like:

```
MyContainer.Register<LoggingService>().As<ILoggingService>();
MyContainer.Register<DataService>().As<IDataService>();
MyContainer.Register<MessagingService>().As<IMessagingService>();
MyContainer.Register<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
MyContainer.Register<AppController>().As<IAppController>();
```

etc.

To get an app controller, I would just call:

```
var controller = MyContainer.Resolve<IAppController>();
```

The container figures out how to construct the IRepostory and IMessagingService and all of their dependencies based on what has been registered. (And if it can't, throw an exception that will hopefully point developers at what's not set up correctly.)

If you want to have a look at what goes on inside an IOC container, have a look at Autofac. It is an open-source container, but a warning, there is a LOT of complex code going on within an IOC container. I'd find it pretty odd that a course lesson would try and have students re-invent the wheel with an IoC container.